# Update table via sql merge not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables.

**book**

This table contains all books with their relevant information.

```
id    title                  author                description
1     Lord of the Rings      J.R.R. Tolkien        ....
2     A Game of Thrones      George R.R. Martin    ....
```

**category**

This table contains all existing book categories.

```
id    product
1     Science-Fiction
2     Thriller
3     Fantasy
4     Action
5     Adventure
```

**book_category**

This table links the book table to the category table. One book can have multiple categories.

```
id    book_id    category_id
1     1          3
2     1          5
3     2          3
4     2          4
5     2          5
```

**Current situation**

With help of a LEFT JOIN sql query I can retrieve all information (book with its categories) and show this on my page.

I have created an edit form where I can change the categories of the book with help of a multiple select. The value of each option in this select is the category_id. This form posts the categories to an array.

**Problem**

What I want is a query to process the posted book with its added/removed categories (in the book_category table).

Currently, I have the following query to update the book_category table based on the book_id and the categories. BUT, it is not working. Who can help me?

EDIT 07/11/17: Not working: It's just the rows not updating. The query seems to run, but without any updates in the database records.

```
$sql = "MERGE book_category AS target
        USING 
            (SELECT *
                FROM ( VALUES
                     (:book_id, :category_id) AS (bid, cid)
                )
            ) AS source
        ON target.book_id = source.bid AND target.category_id = source.cid
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
            INSERT (book_id, category_id) VALUES (:book_id, :category_id)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source THEN 
            DELETE;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($category_id as $c) {        
    $stmt->bindValue(':book_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':category_id', $c, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

EDIT 08/11/17:
While trying to get it to work using mysqli I got the following error:

```
Notice: Wrong SQL:
MERGE book_category AS target
    USING 
        (SELECT *
            FROM ( VALUES (1, 2) AS (bid, cid) )
        ) AS source
ON target.book_id = source.bid AND target.category_id = source.cid
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (book_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 2);

Error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'MERGE book_category AS target USING (SELECT * FROM ( VALUES' at line 1
```

Comment: 1. test your query without PDO and parameters. 2. define "not working".

Comment: Are you getting any Errors ? or it's Just the rows are not updated?

Comment: It's just the rows not updating. The query seems to run, but without any updates in the database records.

Comment: Without PDO it's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you run by 1 parameters (book_id,category_id) in loop this:

   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source THEN DELETE
   always delete all inserted rows except parameters.
   Use

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book_category  WHERE book_id = bid AND category_id = cid )
     INSERT INTO book_category VALUES (book_id,cid )
2. If there are triggers, especially for deletion, one must bear in mind that the merge always causes all triggers of its events

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. I guess the problem is on another point in the query.

Comment: trigger on book_category?